# Return value of next span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return the value of the next/closet span with a certain class ID. I am super close but I am confused how to use `next()` and `closest()` any help would be awesome

HTML:

```
    <table width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <th scope="col">Data</th>
       <tr>
         <td width="20%"><a href="#" class ="show_data_link">Show Data</a>
           <span class="data">1 </span>  
          </td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
         <td width="20%"><a href="#" class ="show_data_link">Show Data</a>
           <span class="data">2 </span>  
          </td>
      </tr>
           <tr>
         <td width="20%"><a href="#" class ="show_data_link">Show Data</a>
           <span class="data">3 </span>  
          </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.show_data_link').bind('click', function(){
//returns the first class
alert($('.data').html());
//returns null
//alert($('.data').next().html());
//returns null
// alert($('.data').closest().html());
  return false;
});
```

If I use `$('.data').html()` i can get the value of the first span just not sure how to get the value of the span that is the closet so the link clicked 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/nW4DJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `alert($(this).next().html());` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nW4DJ/1/)

when you're using `$('.data')` it gets all the elements with `class="data"` no matter witch one you've clicked

Comment: Cool, so I don't even really need the class on the data correct?

Comment: yep, you even don't need class on the links ... you can use `$('table a').click(function(){...});`

Comment: if I wanted to do it with the class is that possible?